# Best way to display this in a form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, user-interface

On my website, I have two tables which are linked using a pivot table. What I am trying to do is let a user update the relationships between the two tables (inserting and removing records from the pivot table). I have no problem doing this in PHP, but what I am concerned about is the way the form is displayed in the users web browser.

The way I am doing it now, is to have a table full of checkboxes, with each checkbox corresponding to a relationship between the column header and the row header (which represent the database tables). The user can check the checkbox to tell the PHP that a record should be present for that relationship (an unchecked box means there is no relationship). However this method can get quite ugly (columns stretching outside page bounds) if there are quite a few columns and quite a few rows, and is a bit tedious to use.

What would be a good way to display this form to the user?

Comment: Can we have some visual clue to what you're describing? A link showing something similar maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a data grid? These are quite powerful:

- [jQuery TableFilter](http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/jquery/tablefilter/tabletest.htm) (click "Go")
- [ExtJS Grid Filter](http://ccinct.com/lab/filter-grid/) (click a small down arrow ▼ that appears near the column name)

It may be a time consuming task to make it work through Ajax, though.

Answer (score 0):

As this is more about the UI of the application than anything else, I don't think there is going to be a single right answer, as it will come down to a combination of what works (which is difficult without being able to see / play with things) and your personal preferences.

A few progressions I would run through:

- **Visual feedback** 
  Make you table more interactive by providing visual feedback to the user.  At the most basic level, try adding some colour to the cells - a colour for those that are checked.  This will allow the user to quickly see which options are "in play".  It may be the reverse of this works better (highlighting unchecked cells) - but this all depends what the form is doing / intending to indicate - i.e. if it's more important to make clear that the unchecked state is bad, you may want these to be red.

The next level up is to add some dynamic highlighting. If the table is huge, you may want to highlight the row and column header cells that correspond the the cell under the cursor.  You could also consider highlight the whole row / column (cross-hair style) to allow the user to examine 'companion' cells.

- **Dynamic table** 
  Slightly more involved would be to add some spice to you table.  Instead of showing rows and columns of check-boxes, use graphical icons / images. They are a lot easier on the eye, and will probably allow you to have tighter control on the dimensions of the table.  The entire UI could then be done via Javascript and on-click - which is pretty easy these days if you employ something like JQuery.
- **Split the interface** 
  *This is based on the assumption that all combinations of Table A & Table B aren't setup in the pivot table to begin with - only when a user tries to relate A.item with B.item*

  Instead of showing all possible combinations, show only those which are active (have an entry in the pivot table).  Then provide the user with a second form (probably of two drop-downs) that allows them to relate a record from the first table to the second.
- **Filter the interface** 
  Provide the user with the ability to filter the interface - to show only the relationships between a single record from one of the tables.  This would have the effect of restricting your table to a single column, making it a bit easier to accommodate in the design.

However, I would still allow the user to get to the "big view" of all records, as, depending on what you are doing, such as view can be very useful to quickly cross reference lots of records.